# 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present' - exception happens "sometimes" in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I get the above error sometimes during the read.  The exception originates from ASP.NET SqlDataReader whenever you try to read data before calling the Read() method.  Since EF does all these internally, I am wondering what else can cause this error.  could it be network (or) db connectivity?

thanks

**Additional Bounty Info (GenericTypeTea):**

I've got the same error after upgrading to EF Code First RC (4.1):

> "Invalid attempt to read when no data
>   is present"

This is the code in question:

```
using (var context = GetContext())
{
    var query = from item in context.Preferences
                where item.UserName == userName
                where item.PrefName == "TreeState"
                select item;

    // Error on this line
    Preference entity = query.FirstOrDefault();
    return entity == null ? null : entity.Value;
}
```

The table structure is as follows:

```
Preference
{
    Username [varchar(50)]
    PrefName [varchar(50)]
    Value [varchar(max)] Nullable
}
```

The table is standalone and has no relationships. This is the DbModelBuilder code:

```
private void ConfigurePreference(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Preference>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserName, x.PrefName });
    builder.Entity<Preference>().ToTable("RP_Preference");
}
```

Exactly the same code works perfectly in CTP5. I'm guessing this is an RC bug, but any ideas of how to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Carnotaurus - Because he's interested in the string "Value."

Comment: Because "return entity" is not the same as "return entity.value"...

Comment: @Ladislav - No need for name-calling.  My rationale was that (just like the CTP's), it would be valuable to have tags for each version before the final release, in case there are bug fixes or API changes.  But I'll defer to your wisdom as an upstanding member of SO.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a large amount of data in the RC release. The difference between the RC and CTP5 is that you need to specify the `[MaxLength]` property that contains a large amount of data.

Comment: Where and how do I specify the MaxLength?

Answer (score 0):

Are you re-using contexts?    I would guess this is happening as a result of something you are doing within `GetContext`

If `GetContext()` provides a stale context, in which the DataReader is closed/corrupted, I could see the above happening.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem on EF4.1 RC1.

POCO:

```
public class Preference
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PrefName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class PreferenceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Preference> Preferences {get;set;}

    public PreferenceContext() 
    :    base("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=_so_question_ef41_rc;Integrated Security=SSPI;") {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ConfigurePreference(modelBuilder);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void ConfigurePreference(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Preference>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserName, x.PrefName });
        builder.Entity<Preference>().ToTable("RP_Preference");
    }
}
```

My little Console App:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userName = "Anon";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var p = GetPreference(userName);                
        }
    }

    private static string GetPreference(string userName)
    {
        using (var context = new PreferenceContext())
        {
            var query = from item in context.Preferences
                            where item.UserName == userName
                            where item.PrefName == "TreeState"
                            select item;

            // Error on this line
            Preference entity = query.FirstOrDefault();
            return entity == null ? null : entity.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I do 10,000 reads, and no error.  You will need to post more complete code to continue.

Comment: ... Maybe there's something wrong happening in your GetContext() method.  Let's start there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with GetContext(). It just returns `new Context(connectionString);` It only happens when value contains a large amount of data. About 10K+.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the CommandTimeout on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with EF4 - In my case I was (trying to) return the list of entities within the using{} section. This is the same as you are doing in your question:

```
return entity == null ? null : entity.Value;
```

} // end using

I moved the return to after the } and it worked.

I think I had the problem because the code was in a function which had *already* queried the database in another using block, I suspect the table was locking but not reporting the error, ending the using block before the return released the database lock.

Steve